# Google Sheets - Data Validation - Using Formula in List from range

Tags: validation, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

[image]

I am trying to create a custom dropdown for each row depending on the content of a cell in the same row. I have tried several other ways but they do not work when you filter.

The formula I am using will be put in the range section here.

this is the formula :

```
=concatenate("'Working'!$AG",(match(C2,Working!D:D,0)),":","$AK",(match(C2,Working!D:D,0)))
```

This would output Working!$AG3:$AK3 which would be a valid range and return the correct result. Help, please

Comment: Why is it tagged with 'excel'?

Comment: I thought excel users may have an idea of how this could be resolved

Comment: Can you share a public copy of the sheet you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible. No formulae other than simple range references can be used in conditional formatting criteria when `List from a range` is selected

(currently in June 2022)